# Zend Framwork Session on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, zend-db, zend-session

Still couldn't make it works after post this link:
[Zend framework session lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776097/zend-framework-session-lost)

I have this Sign up form that allow users to register and redirect them right away to their pages. All work great on every browsers except **INTERNET EXPLORER**.

I have tried different ways, but still can't make it to work.
After the user is saved to database the session won't store.
But if I take out the save of the user, the session and cookies can be store.

Here's the code:

```
public function signUpAction()
{
    $signupForm = new Application_Form_UserSignUp();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {

        if ($signupForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
        {
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->createRow($signupForm->getValues());
            if ($user->save())
            {
                //Set email into cookies for displaying into login inputfield
                setcookie('display_email', $this->getRequest()->getParam('email'), time() + 3600*24*30, '/'); <-- not working
                Zend_Session::rememberMe(186400 * 14); <-- not working
                Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user); <-- not working

                $user->sendSignUpEmail(); <-- i'm receiving this email
                $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoRoute(array(), 'invite');                   
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->signupForm = $signupForm;
```

Here's another way I'm doing but still doesn't working on **IE**:

```
public function signUpAction()
{

    $users = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
    $signupForm = new Application_Form_UserSignUp();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        $firstname = $this->getRequest()->getParam('first_name');
        $lastname = $this->getRequest()->getParam('last_name');
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');

        if ($signupForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
        {
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->createRow($signupForm->getValues());

            $user = array('email' => $email, 'first_name' => $firstname, 'last_name' => $last_name);
            $users->insert($user);
            Zend_Session::rememberMe(186400 * 14);
            Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);
            $this->_redirect('invite');
        }
    }
    $this->view->signupForm = $signupForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before calling the redirect.  Or I think Zend has an equivalent, see: Zend_Session::writeclose

Only other thing that comes to mind (with IE being the only browser giving you trouble) is P3P policy.  Look at Talha's post here: [Zend Sessions problem with IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084008/zend-sessions-problem-with-ie8)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look, been a week was trying to fix it..